# MERN Stack with Mongoose and Heroku 503 on logging out a user

Tags: javascript, react-native, express, heroku, mongoose

I am building out a React Native App with User authentication.  Every time I 'logout' a user (using JWT). I get logged out, then after x seconds a 503 throws.  and Heroku Crashes, I have to manually restart the Heroku Dyno each time, (or wait the 10 min)

Packages:

Backend:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-jwt": "^6.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.6",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
```

Front end:

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.8",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "undefined": "@react-native/community/masked-view"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Backend App.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
require('dotenv/config');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const errorHandler = require('./helpers/error-handler');

//cors
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

const productsRouter = require('./routers/products');
const categoriesRouter = require('./routers/categories');
const ordersRouter = require('./routers/orders');
const usersRouter = require('./routers/users');
const authJwt = require('./helpers/jwt');

const api = process.env.API_URL;

// MiddleWare
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(authJwt());
app.use('/public/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/public/uploads'));
app.use(errorHandler);

// Routers
app.use(`${api}/categories`, categoriesRouter);
app.use(`${api}/orders`, ordersRouter);
app.use(`${api}/products`, productsRouter);
app.use(`${api}/users`, usersRouter);

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_STRING)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('database connection is ready');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });


// Development
// app.listen(3000, () => {
//   console.log('JamComMobile BE running on http://localhost:3000');
// });

// Production 
let server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function () {
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Express is working on port ' + port)
})

server.on('clientError', (err, socket) => {
  console.error(err);
  socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n');
});
```

Backend Users Model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    passwordHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    street: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    apartment: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    zip :{
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    country: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }

});

userSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
    return this._id.toHexString();
});

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
});

exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
exports.userSchema = userSchema;
```

Backend jwt.js

```js
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');

function authJwt() {
  const secret = process.env.secret;
  const api = process.env.API_URL;
  return expressJwt({
    secret,
    algorithms: ['HS256'],
    isRevoked: isRevoked,
  }).unless({
    path: [
      { url: /\/public\/uploads(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/products(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/categories(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/orders(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST'] },
      // { url: /\/api\/v1\/users(.*)/, methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS'] },
      { url: /\/api\/v1\/users\/.*/, methods: ['GET'] },
      `${api}/users/login`,
      `${api}/users/register`,
    ],
  });
}

//TODO: need to clean this up and add additional roles
//this rejects the api call if user is not admin
// async function isRevoked(req, payload, done) {
//   if (!payload.isAdmin) {
//     done(null, true);
//   }

//   done();
// }

async function isRevoked(req, token) { // token now contains payload data

  if(!token.payload.isAdmin) {

      return true // if the isAdmin flag in payload is false, then we reject the token

  }

  return false ;

}



module.exports = authJwt;
```

Frontend UserProfile.js (with logout methods)

```js
import React, { useContext, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Container } from 'native-base';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import axios from 'axios';
import baseURL from '../../assets/common/baseUrl';

import AuthGlobal from '../../Context/store/AuthGlobal';
import { logoutUser } from '../../Context/actions/auth.actions';

const UserProfile = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(AuthGlobal);
  const [userProfile, setUserProfile] = useState();

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      if (
        context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === false ||
        context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === null
      ) {
        props.navigation.navigate('Login');
      }

      AsyncStorage.getItem('jwt')
        .then((res) => {
          axios
            .get(`${baseURL}users/${context.stateUser.user.userId}`, {
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${res}` },
            })
            .then((user) => setUserProfile(user.data));
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));

      return () => {
        setUserProfile();
      };
    }, [context.stateUser.isAuthenticated]),
  );

  return (
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.subContainer}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>
          {userProfile ? userProfile.name : ''}
        </Text>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>
            Email: {userProfile ? userProfile.email : ''}
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ margin: 10 }}>
            Phone: {userProfile ? userProfile.phone : ''}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ marginTop: 80 }}>
          <Button
            title={'Sign Out'}
            onPress={() => [
              logoutUser(context.dispatch),
              AsyncStorage.removeItem('jwt').catch(
                (error) => console.log(error) 
              ),
            ]}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </Container>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  subContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: 60,
  },
});

export default UserProfile;
```

React Context API AuthActions.js

```js
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Toast from 'react-native-toast-message';
import baseURL from '../../assets/common/baseUrl';

export const SET_CURRENT_USER = 'SET_CURRENT_USER';

export const loginUser = (user, dispatch) => {
  fetch(`${baseURL}users/login`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        const token = data.token;
        AsyncStorage.setItem('jwt', token);
        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded, user));
      } else {
        logoutUser(dispatch);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      Toast.show({
        topOffset: 60,
        type: 'error',
        text1: 'Please provide correct credentials in order to login',
      });
      logoutUser(dispatch);
    });
};

export const getUserProfile = (id) => {
  fetch(`${baseURL}users/${id}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
};

export const logoutUser = (dispatch) => {
  AsyncStorage.removeItem('jwt');
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
};

export const setCurrentUser = (decoded, user) => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded,
    userProfile: user,
  };
};
```

AuthReducer.js:

```js
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from "../actions/auth.actions";
import isEmpty from "../../assets/common/isEmpty";

export default function (state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
     case SET_CURRENT_USER: 
        return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
            user: action.payload,
            userProfile: action.userProfile
        };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

Auth.js (from STORE):

```js
import React, { useReducer, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import authReducer from '../reducers/auth.reducer';
import { setCurrentUser } from '../actions/auth.actions';

import AuthGlobal from './AuthGlobal';

const Auth = (props) => {
  const [stateUser, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
    isAuthenticated: null,
    user: {},
  });
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowChild(true);
    if (AsyncStorage.jwt) {
      const decoded = AsyncStorage.jwt ? AsyncStorage.jwt : '';
      if (setShowChild) {
        dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwt_decode(decoded)));
      }
    }
    return () => setShowChild(false);
  }, []);

  if (!showChild) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <AuthGlobal.Provider
        value={{
          stateUser,
          dispatch,
        }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </AuthGlobal.Provider>
    );
  }
};

export default Auth;
```

Stack Trace from Expo

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 503]
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:16:9 in settle
at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:57:6 in onloadend
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:614:6 in setReadyState
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:396:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter.js:135:10 in EventEmitter#emit
```

Heroku Log :

```c
2022-05-21T15:59:08.640508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/api/v1/users/undefined" host=<HIDDEN> request_id=9f36d0a5-6b50-4b33-89f3-1d9f16302954 fwd="<HIDDEN>" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

On the surface it appears to be some kind of issue where either Heroku is waiting for a response and wont get one since we revoke the jwt token from asyncstorage

Comment: It is not a proper logout if you only remove the JWT from the client. After I have logged out, the server must not accept the JWT any more, even if someone else stole it. (That's the major reason why people log out.) In other words: You must instruct the server to invalidate the JWT.

Comment: Agreed on its not a proper logout, any suguestions on how to improve the logout @HeikoTheißen ?

Comment: Make use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt#user-content-revoked-tokens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The erroneous request `GET /api/v1/users/undefined` could result from the following part of your code:

```js
if (context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === false ||
    context.stateUser.isAuthenticated === null) {
  props.navigation.navigate('Login');
}
// "else" missing here?
AsyncStorage.getItem('jwt').then((res) => {
  axios.get(`${baseURL}users/${context.stateUser.user.userId}`, ...
```

because the `axios.get` statement is executed even if no user is authenticated.

Comment: this stops the 503 when logging out, I can't quite connect why this stops the 503 from happening on LOGOUT by adding the ELSE clause to the login method?

Comment: The problematic code is executed whenever `context.stateUser.isAuthenticated` changes, also after logout.

Comment: thank you !  I can't believe i missed something as simple as a catch block!